# unable to save chart as image

Tags: jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, canvg

I have written a function to save the chart as image.Below i have mentioned code which i have written :
HTML:

```
<div> <span id="save" onclick="javascript:saveChart1();"  style="height:10px;width:40px; color:#000;"> comment</span></div> 
<div id="chart_load"></div>
<div id="chart_save">
     <canvas id="chart_area" height="300px" width="415px"></canvas>
</div>
```

Javescript:

```
function saveChart1()
{

             var outcan=document.getElementById("chart_area");
               var obj=document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");                
                var ctx=outcan.getContext("2d");        
                ctx.drawImage(obj[1],0,0);        
                html2canvas($("#chart_save"), {
                        onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
        // toDataURL defaults to png, so we need to request a jpeg, then convert for file download.
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        a.download = 'ss.jpg';
        a.click();

                    }
                        });
}
```

When i click on save button then getting below mentioned error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
    at saveChart1 (generatedContent:310)
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick
```

Can any one suggest me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a working example on jsfiddle or codepen.io?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `obj[0]`?

Comment: @ArnoldSchrijver: if i use obj[0] then i am getting blank image?

Comment: @Difster: i have created the jsfiddle for that :https://jsfiddle.net/sam140/0b7omvcx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var obj = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        // toDataURL defaults to png, so we need to request a jpeg, then convert for file download.
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        a.download = 'ss.jpg';
        a.click();
    }
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sodofkcs/969/)

Comment: Getting below mentioned error :Uncaught TypeError: html2canvas(...).then is not a function
    at saveChart1 (generatedContent:302)
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick (generatedContent:85)
html2canvas.js:2769 Uncaught TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function
    at html2canvas.js:2769
    at Object._html2canvas.Renderer (html2canvas.js:2552)
    at Object.options.complete (html2canvas.js:2667)
    at start (html2canvas.js:2082)
    at Object._html2canvas.Preload (html2canvas.js:2368)
    at html2canvas.js:2678

Comment: You want to convert your chart into image Right? Check my updated answer

Comment: chart is not rendering proper..for example if i want to export the bar chart as image then i am getting only x and ya axis values nothing else.even no bar is created ..